# avoid redeclaring an interface for more one time

Tags: php

I have an interface which I named `Manager`, and two classes `UtilisateurManager` and `StageManager`, and the both of them implements the `Manager` interface.

In each class I included the interface `Manager` as the following :

```
require '../helpers/Manager.class.php';
```

Then I needed to use these two classes at once in a `php` script, but I got the error that `I can't redeclare class Manager`.

I tried to work with the function `class_exists()` but it's not useful in my case.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `require_once` instead of `require`.

```
require_once '../helpers/Manager.class.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a simple autoloader which will try to load class/interface only if it isn't already loaded, and forget about direct require/include then. It is considered good practice to leave the filesystem details out of the class file: you may reuse it in other project where your directories system might change, so you'll need to edit the class again.

A simple example:

```
class Autoloader
{
    protected $directories = array();
    public function register()
    {
        // register 'loadClass' method as an autoloader
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }
    public function addSource($dir)
    {
        $this->directories[] = $dir;
    }
    public function loadClass($className)
    {
        foreach ($this->directories as $dir) { // search in every registered sources root
            $fileName = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$className.'.class.php';
            if (file_exists($fileName) {
                include($fileName);
                return; // halt when file was found
            }
        }
    }
}
// bootstrap file
$autoloader = new Autoloader;
$autoloader->register();
```

([spl_autoload_register documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php))

Please note that this realization will cycle through the folders, and this is certainly not the desired solution. The best option today is to build project according to [PSR-4 spec](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md) - autoloader implementation will have to check existence of a single file only. It may be a little hard to dive into namespaces without any preparation, but once you get familiar with this coding style, you will forget about direct file load.

The last thing, i want to warn you about your naming convention - your `Interface` is stored in a `.class.php` file, and this is confusing.